# What happen under the hood when I call an extrinsic function?

Tags: runtime, architecture

For example if I call a function from a custom pallet that set a random number on chain this elaboration is done by a single node or by the entire network with some sort of virtualization?

Comment: There is also a good post here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/transactions-lifecycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is detailed information on the transaction lifecycle here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/transaction-lifecycle

Video:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pfM0GOp02c